# What is the purpose of the left shift in this DP problem?

Tags: c

I recently found this solution online for this problem (original from leetcode.com):

In the "100 game," two players take turns adding, to a running total, any integer from 1..10. The player who first causes the running total to reach or exceed 100 wins. 
What if we change the game so that players cannot re-use integers? 
For example, two players might take turns drawing from a common pool of numbers of 1..15 without replacement until they reach a total >= 100.

Given an integer `maxChoosableInteger` and another integer `desiredTotal`, determine if the first player to move can force a win, assuming both players play optimally. 
You can always assume that `maxChoosableInteger` will not be larger than 20 and `desiredTotal` will not be larger than 300.

```c
int canWin(int *dp, int v, int m, int total) {
    int i, hewins;

    if (dp[v] != -1) return dp[v];      // already resolved

    for (i = m; i >= 1; i --) {
        if (v & (1 << (i - 1))) continue;
        v |= (1 << (i - 1));
        if (i >= total) {
            dp[v] = 1;          // resolve to win
            return 1;
        }
        hewins = canWin(dp, v, m, total - i);
        if (!hewins) return 1;
        v &= ~(1 << (i - 1));   // not able to resolve, try with different number
    }
    dp[v] = 0;      // resolve to loose
    return 0;
}
bool canIWin(int maxChoosableInteger, int desiredTotal) {
    int w, dp[1 << 20];

    // none can win
    if (maxChoosableInteger * (maxChoosableInteger + 1) / 2 < desiredTotal) return false;

    //dp = calloc((1 << (maxChoosableInteger)), sizeof(int));
    //assert(dp);
    memset(dp, -1, (1 << (maxChoosableInteger)) * sizeof(int));

    w = canWin(dp, 0, maxChoosableInteger, desiredTotal);

    //free(dp);

    return w;
}
```

In the above code, there are 3 main instances where the leftshift is used.

```c
    memset(dp, -1, (1 << (maxChoosableInteger)) * sizeof(int));
```

and

```c
dp[1 << 20]
```

and all the instances of something like:

```
        if (v & (1 << (i - 1))) continue;
```

The solution to the problem is recursive and this one is solved recursively but first of all I'm not sure why you would need such a huge array to store all the recursive calls. At most there should be 20 recursive calls for each input (since `canIWin(maxinteger, total) = canIWin(maxInteger - 1), total)` `OR` `canIWin((maxInteger - 2), total)` `OR` ... `canIWin(1, total)` (It can't actually go to 1 because of logical reasons, but this just gets the idea across)

Any explanation of why this kind of left shift is used would be appreciated.

Comment: `1 << n` is equivalent to `2` raised to the power `n`. Does that help?

Comment: `v & (1 << (i - 1)` tests whether the nth bit is set in `v`. This allows `v` to be used as a compact array of flags.

Comment: @Barmar I know what bitwise leftshift  means, just conceptually why is it being used here?

Comment: `1 << 20` is just another way to write `0x100000` or `1048576`

Comment: @Barmar yes, but I think the 20 has to do with the fact that that is the maximum size of the choosable number. I was wondering why they chose that size of array, why does it have to be that big?

Comment: The `memset` is just setting the first `2**maxChoosableInteger` elements to `-1`.

Comment: It seems to be an array of combinations, so there's an element for every combination of two plays.

Comment: This question requires that we be mind readers, trying to 'second guess' what was the original writer thinking when they wrote the code.  I.E, this question is off-topic